# RigidBody moving automatically to upper left in Space Shooter tutorial

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am following the space shooter tutorial on Unity website.

I have completed upto movement actions of the player object.

When I start my game, the spaceship automatomatically moves to the upper left corner even when no input is given.

I have followed the tutorial exactly as it is. Even the completed scene that is available in the Asset Store is having the same problem.

I am using Unity 5.3.

```
PlayerController.cs

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary
{
    public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;


}


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {


public float speed;
public Boundary boundary;
public float tilt;

// Use this for initialization
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = movement * speed;

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.x,boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),  
        0.0f,
        Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax));


    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0, GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x * -tilt);
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct and since you say that the demo scene does the same, I suppose that the problem comes from your Axis input: The lines taht add movement

```
float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

Uses the Axes called `Horizontal` and `Vertical`. It is possible that on your instance of unity, these input are linked to a device that sends events (you maybe have a controller plugged...)

To test this, You can add the following line below reading the input:

```
float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
Debug.Log("Movement: " + moveHorizontal + ", " + moveVertical); // <-- add this
```

This will write the values you get as input. If you don't touch anything, they should be zero. If they are not zero, Go to `Edit -> Project Settings -> Input`, You will see how your keyboard, mouse and other controllers are linked to events in Unity such as `Horizontal` and `Vertical`

See http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html for more info on Input Manager

Good luck!

Comment: thanks .... in Edit -> Project Settings -> Input the horizontal and vertical axes were connected to a joystick.